# How to import a Ms Acess database and a folder with multiple images linked to the acess database into a SQL script?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, import, type-conversion

i am new to SQL and i want to import a Ms Acess database and a folder with multiple images linked to the acess database into a SQL script or to phpmyadmin. My plan after that is to display the database on a html website that will show the images and the data they are linked with.

An alternative could be converting the database that is in a ASP.NET file directly to a sql database which would be a lot simpler.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there not really any much (code) I can find that will script out a access database.

However, there are beyond buckets of ways to get the data out. I mean, you can export as a csv file. Or import to Excel. Or in my case, I just send the Access data to say SQL server. once that data is exported out, then your resulting text file, or say imported tables to sql server can be consumed.

and once you have the data in sql server? Well, then you probably don't need any scripting out of the tables (and or data).

So, you can use SSMS tools to import a access table into a sql server table.

However, it VERY much depends on how complex the Access data is? If it just a table? Then as noted, you have as many options or more then flavors of ice cream.

But, if the data is "related" and there are multiple tables? Well, ok, we now into a different realm and task at hand. For related data imports to sql server, then I use SSMA (sql migration wizard for Access).

So either SSMA or even just SSMS (sql server studio) can import access data.

Thus, once in that database, then you can quite much consume that data like any and all web sites consume data from SQL server.

Of course, you will have to convert the path names to the pictures to "URL" format based on your web site. (or provide a function to do this).

This would suggest that your web site will now need a "virtual" folder that points to the server folder with those images. Do keep in mind if you do this, then users can type in any URL to see/read/use/grab any picture in that folder.

Another alterative is to NOT include that "fake folder" that points to the actual folder on the server, and have your code behind "read" + "spit out" the pictures. This can be a bit of code, but then it means that the web site (browser) does NOT need to resolve nor have path names to the pictures. (but you code behind of course can read any file and just about any location on that network - just not the web browser can do this.

I think much of either two above choices (static URL to the pictures), or code behind to fetch and read the file and stream it down to the browser will be a issue of security concerns, and ALSO very much that if you hosting the server on your own network, or plane to host the site via some hosting service (in that case, then you have to copy up the pictures to the web server hosting - so probably just having URL's to the pictures will suffice. It much depends as noted on how your hosting site is to be setup.